# Why is there duplicate columns auto generating in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I find that this generating when I assign Tolist to datagridview datasource. I also tried store procedure and its working as aspeacted.
I'm probably missing something simple to prevent duplication, but I can't see it.
How to prevent duplicate record in DataGridView.

[image: duplicate columns image here]

Code:

```
public partial class ProductsUserControl : UserControl
{
    LinqtoSqlDataContext db = new LinqtoSqlDataContext();
    public ProductsUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgv.DataSource = db.Products.ToList();           
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the all duplicate columns are foreign keys columns in my product table.

Comment: Can you post the code for `LinqtoSqlDataContext`?  Or the `Products` definition?

Comment: the LinqtoSqlDataContext code generated by default when I add new item LinqToSqlDataClasses in my project after that simply I drag my all tables from visual studio server explorer to drop in LinqtoSql.dbml table section and its display as diagram.

Comment: Seems like something is off with your `Product` class definition.  I'd have to see that, auto-generated or not, to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a data context that combines two tables. If that is the case, it would be helpful to post the table structure. Also how the data context is defined. Its common to convert reference to actual value with data contexts.

Comment: Note: the all duplicate columns are foreign keys columns in my product table.